# Starting a job using configuration

Tags: java, spring-batch, pojo

Is there a way to define a default job which will start when the context is loaded, without having to programmatically call `jobLauncher.run(mainJob, jobParameters);` ?

Answer (score 0):

No. You have to register an [`ApplicationListener`](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/context/ApplicationListener.html) and launch job manually.